# SQL Plus (Oracle 11)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I know which is the largest table in the database and who owns it?

```
SELECT 
   segment_name           TABLE_NAME,       
   SUM(bytes)  table_size
FROM
   USER_SEGMENTS
WHERE
   SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE'  
GROUP BY segment_name
```

or should I use (`TOP`) or (`rowcount`)

Answer (score 0):

Rownum won't help you here as rownums are calculated before ordering and you want the largest table.

```
with q as (
  Select segment_name as table_name,
         sum(bytes) as table_size
    from user_segments
   group by segment_name
) select hlp.table_name, hlp.table_size
from (Select q.*, dense_rank() over(order by q.table_size desc) as rn from q) hlp
where hlp.rn = 1;
```

This will do the trick. The with clause is a Common Table Expression [(CTE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression%20(CTE)), valid in the context of the following select under the alias "q". I wanted to avoid multiple calls to sum.

The dense_rank() function inside the subquery in the from clause assings consecutive to the values of a partition or an order, which in our case is the descending table size.

The subquery is needed to select the first row.

Regarding the use of the data dictionary tables i haven't checked the result.